# How to CREATE TABLE in BIgQuery?

Tags: error-handling, google-bigquery, create-table

I'm trying to create a temporary table on BigQuery but an error keeps pupping up. The **Portfolio_Covid_Data** is the dataset and **percentage_population_vaccinated** the table I'm creating. The code I'm running is:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Portfolio_Covid_Data.percentage_population_vaccinated
CREATE TABLE Portfolio_Covid_Data.percentage_population_vaccinated 
(dea.continent STRING, 
   dea.location STRING,
   dea.date DATE,
   dea.population NUMERIC,
   vac.new_vaccinations NUMERIC,
   rolling_people_vaccinated NUMERIC)

INSERT INTO Portfolio_Covid_Data.percentage_population_vaccinated
  SELECT 
   dea.continent, 
   dea.location,
   dea.date,
   dea.population,
   vac.new_vaccinations,
   SUM(vac.new_vaccinations) OVER (PARTITION BY dea.location ORDER BY dea.location,dea.date ) AS rolling_people_vaccinated
FROM 
   `big-dataset.Portfolio_Covid_Data.covid_deaths` AS dea
JOIN
     `big-dataset.Portfolio_Covid_Data.covid_vaccinations` AS vac
     ON dea.location = vac.location
     AND dea.date = vac.date 
 
SELECT 
    *,
    ROUND((rolling_people_vaccinated/population)*100,2) AS percentage_population_vaccinated
FROM 
    Portfolio_Covid_Data.percentage_population_vaccinated
```

Comment: Please include the error message you are seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do `dea` and `vac` refer to in your CREATE TABLE statement?

This worked for me

```sql
CREATE TABLE Portfolio_Covid_Data.percentage_population_vaccinated 
(continent STRING, 
   location STRING,
   date DATE,
   population NUMERIC,
   new_vaccinations NUMERIC,
   rolling_people_vaccinated NUMERIC)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! `dea` is the alias for the covid_deaths table and `vac` is the alias for the covid_vaccinations table. I ran the query with your answer but it's still giving me an error. The error says: ***Syntax error: Expected end of input but got keyword CREATE at [2:1]***

Comment: Are you running the whole script? Run each statement individually or put semi-colons at the end of each statement.

Comment: I tried running each statement individually or putting semi-colons at the end but it still won't work. Could it be because I'm using the free version of BigQuery?